# Arranging an Image and a Component on the same line

Tags: reactjs

```
<header className={styles.body}>
    <img src={logo} id={styles.logo} alt="logo" />
    <DropDown id={styles.dropDown}/>         
</header>

body {
    margin:10px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    /* display: inline-block; */
}

#dropDrown {
    float: right;
}
```

I have this header component that I want to put an image as well as a "DropDown" component on the same line, but it tends to wrap under the image and I cannot get it to render on the same line, any tips/tricks the Dropdown renders an image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this CSS would help:

```
body {
    margin:10px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items:center;
}
```

And remove your dropdown CSS

More about flexbox:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: same issue still occurs it just in the middle now, thanks tho.

Comment: edited my answer, tweak with flex properties to achieve what you want

Comment: Still renders it below the logo image, maybe it has to do with the properties of the dropdown css?